# Объединение списка словарей

Tags: python, json, list, словари

Помогите пожалуйста с ситуацией.
Получаю два ответа в формате **JSON**.

```
eventList = 
    [
        {'id': '1', 'name': 'someName1'},
        {'id': '2', 'name': 'someName2'},
        {'id': '3', 'name': 'someName2'}
    ]

statistic = 
    [
         {'id': '1', 'members': '428'}, 
         {'id': '2', 'members': '117'}
    ]
```

Надо их объединить:

```
result = 
    [
         {'id': '1', 'name': 'someName1', 'members': '428'}, 
         {'id': '2', 'name': 'someName2', 'members': '117'},
         {'id': '3', 'name': 'someName2'}
    ]
```

Опыта не так много и сам смогу реализовать лишь топорно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал так:

```
eventList = [
        {'id': '1', 'name': 'someName1'},
        {'id': '2', 'name': 'someName2'},
        {'id': '3', 'name': 'someName2'}
    ]

statistic = [
         {'id': '1', 'members': '428'}, 
         {'id': '2', 'members': '117'}
    ]

dict1 = dict((obj['id'], obj) for obj in eventList)
dict2 = dict((obj['id'], obj) for obj in statistic)

res = [dict1.get(key, dict()) | dict2.get(key, dict()) for key in set(list(dict1.keys()) + list(dict2.keys()))]

print(res)
```

можно и покороче сделать вариант:

```
res = [dict1.get(key, dict()) | dict2.get(key, dict()) for key in (dict1 | dict2).keys()]
```

правда более ресурсоемко будет ибо идет объединение словарей, хотя достаточно лишь получить совокупность ключей двух словарей (как в первом примере)

Comment: Спасибо! Интересное решение с выносом айдишника за пределы тела. Я даже не думал в подобном ключе.

Comment: вроде как вместо этого `set(list(dict1.keys()) + list(dict2.keys()))` должно сработать `dict1.keys() | dict2.keys()` _Keys views are set-like_

Comment: @SergFSM, да, думаю ваш вариант является наиболее оптимальным

Answer (score 1):

Костыли для более ранних версий питона

```
def implict(main, other):
    '''
    update list of dict recursive, using 'id' as key

    >>>implict([{'id':'1','n':'A'},{'id':'2','n':'B'}],[{'id':'3','n':'C'},{'id':'1','n':'NOT A'},{'id':'2','not n':'not n'}])
    [{'id': '2', 'n': 'B'}, {'id': '1', 'n': 'A'}, {'id': '2', 'not n': 'not n', 'n': 'B'}]
    '''
    res=[]
    for elementA in other:
        for elementB in main:
            if elementA['id']==elementB['id']:
                subres={}
                subres.update(elementA)
                subres.update(elementB)
                res.append(subres)

                elementA=subres #fix 
        
        if elementA not in res:
                    res.append(elementB)

    print(res)
    return(res)
```

Comment: Ну вот я сам примерно в таком ключе и думал и надеялся что есть вариант элегантней.

Comment: @MikhailIvanov возможно через датафреймы pandas выйдет элегантнее

Answer (score 1):

еще одно решение через промежуточный словарь:

```
from itertools import chain

res_dict = {}
for d in chain(eventList, statistic):
    res_dict.setdefault(d['id'], {}).update(d)
res_list = list(res_dict.values())
```

результат:

```
print(res_list)
'''
[{'id': '1', 'name': 'someName1', 'members': '428'},
 {'id': '2', 'name': 'someName2', 'members': '117'},
 {'id': '3', 'name': 'someName2'}]
'''
```

**UPD**

В комментариях было предложение решить с помощью `pandas`. У меня получилось как-то так:

```
import pandas as pd

res = pd.DataFrame(eventList).merge(pd.DataFrame(statistic), 
                                    how='outer').fillna('0').to_dict('records')
```

результат такой:

```
[{'id': '1', 'name': 'someName1', 'members': '428'},
 {'id': '2', 'name': 'someName2', 'members': '117'},
 {'id': '3', 'name': 'someName2', 'members': '0'}]
```